# IndexedDB: How to use multiple indexes along with 'multiEntry: true'

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, indexeddb

If I got these data in an indexedDB:

```
{
  name:"Ray",
  age:20,
  tags:["apple","banana","beer"]
}

{
  name:"Scott",
  age:25,
  tags:["beer"]
}

{
  name:"Marc",
  age:28,
  tags:["mongo","jenkins"]
}
```

Then I want to find persons who have tag 'beer' and ordered the result by age, what should I do?

According to this article http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/8/10/Searching-for-array-elements-in-IndexedDB, 'multiEntry: true' should be applied to query array field, but it'll show an error if I use it with multiple indexes. So what query can achieve the goal? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In `onupgradeneeded` callback function:

```
store.createIndex('tagsIndex','tags', {multiEntry: true});
```

In your query section, do

```
var tx = db.transaction('store');
var tagsIndex = tx.objectStore('store').index('tagsIndex');
var beerQuery = tagsIndex.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only('beer'));
var people = [];
beerQuery.onsuccess = function(event) {
  var cursor = this.result;
  if(!cursor) return;
  people.push(cursor.value);
  cursor.continue();
};

tx.oncomplete = function() {
  onGetPeopleWhoLikeBeerSortedByAgeAsc(people.sort(function(p1, p2) {
    if(p1.age > p2.age) return -1;
    if(p1.age == p2.age) return 0;
    return 1;
  }));
};
```

Comment: I think you will need to sort the data *after* you get the initial result set.

Comment: I like your technique to say `if (!cursor) return`. I will use that from now on.

Comment: Are there any limits that you know of on a number of items that can be kept in a multiEntry index and a single property in general?